# Hibernate 5 slow startup using OrbisSQLServerDialect

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

We are migrating our project to Hibernate 5 and are experiencing slow startup times.

Hibernate seems to be spending a lot of time in `org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker`

```
2018-02-06 07:24:49,167 DEBUG [org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker] - <Visiting attribute path : s23>
2018-02-06 07:24:49,167 DEBUG [org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker] - <Visiting attribute path : s24>
2018-02-06 07:24:49,167 DEBUG [org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker] - <Visiting attribute path : s25>
2018-02-06 07:24:49,167 DEBUG [org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker] - <Visiting attribute path : s26>
2018-02-06 07:24:49,167 DEBUG [org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker] - <Visiting attribute path : s27>
2018-02-06 07:24:49,167 DEBUG [org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker] - <Visiting attribute path : s28>
2018-02-06 07:24:49,167 DEBUG [org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker] - <Visiting attribute path : s29>
2018-02-06 07:24:49,167 DEBUG [org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker] - <Visiting attribute path : s30>
2018-02-06 07:24:49,167 DEBUG [org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker] - <Visiting attribute path : s31>
```

Here is how Hibernate is configured:

```
hibernateProp.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");
hibernateProp.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS,"org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext");
hibernateProp.put(Environment.DIALECT, "com.orbis.portal.OrbisSQLServerDialect");
hibernateProp.put("org.hibernate.flushMode", "COMMIT");
hibernateProp.put(Environment.USE_QUERY_CACHE, "true");
hibernateProp.put(Environment.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY, "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory");
hibernateProp.put(Environment.CACHE_PROVIDER_CONFIG, "classpath:ehcache.xml");
hibernateProp.put(Environment.USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE, "true");
hibernateProp.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true");
hibernateProp.put("hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys", "true");
```

And here is how the session factory is built:

```
final BootstrapServiceRegistry bootstrapServiceRegistry = new BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .enableAutoClose()
                .applyIntegrator(MetadataExtractorIntegrator.INSTANCE).build();

registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder(bootstrapServiceRegistry)
                .applySettings(getHibernateSettings()).build();

MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

processHbmMappings(sources);

processAnnotatedMappings(sources);

Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
```

Any ideas?

Update:

OrbisSQLServerDialect simply extends SQLServer2008Dialect to alter a couple column types

```
public class OrbisSQLServerDialect extends SQLServer2008Dialect
{
    public OrbisSQLServerDialect()
    {
        super();
        registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "datetime");
        registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "tinyint");
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "slow" startup times and "spending a lot of time in MetamodelGraphWalker"?

Comment: Before the migration startup took a minute and a half. After the migration startup takes about 4 minutes. When we set logging to DEBUG we see that a lot of time is spent in org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker

Comment: can you tell us how much time is spent in `MetamodelGraphWalker`?

Comment: Going by just the logs, it seems to be about 3 minutes

 `2018-02-06 08:23:48,870 to 2018-02-06 08:27:12,663`

Comment: you should read the documentation for `org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker` and understand what it does. once you got this, you should be able to stop it (not sure what side effects it has)